# Calculated Param from DAG

Tags: airflow

I have this function, which I would like to pass as a DAG parameter,

```py
def week_id(dt: str) -> int:
    dt0: date = date.fromisoformat(dt)
    return dt0.year * 100 + dt0.isocalendar()[1]

with DAG(
    dag_id="my_dag",
    description="My awesome pipeline",
    params={
        "week_id": week_id(" {{ next_ds }} "),
    },
    schedule_interval="0 23 * * 0",
) as dag:
    # tasks run here using {{ params.week_id }}
```

I have problems with Jinja rendering, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the next_ds is a value that depend on that the dag_run and not on the definition of the dag. you should calculate it inside the dag (in python operator for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
get_week_id = PythonOperator(
    task_id="get_week_id",
    python_callable=week_id,
    op_kwargs={"dt": "{{ ds }}"},
)

# reuse the value with xcoms
week_id = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_week_id', key='return_value') }}"

second_task = ... # use week_id inside

with DAG(...) as dag:
   get_week_id >> second_task
```